# Arrow to constant in align environment

Tags: align, tikz-arrows

I wanted to know how I can point to a variable in the align environment so the I can get an output that looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning,fit,arrows.meta,}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  D(\lambda,x) = & ~ f(x) + \lambda'g(x) \quad \lambda\geqslant 0\\
\intertext{the dual is given as:}
\lambda^{*} = & ~ arg\{ \max_{\lambda}D(\lambda,x^{*}) \}\\
            = & ~ arg\{ \max_{\lambda}D(\lambda) \}
\end{align*}

%\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
%\draw[blue,thick,->] (d1) to [in=90,out=245] + (198:2.5cm) node[anchor=north,text = black] {const.};
%\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: you should write `\arg`, not just `arg`.

Comment: I think you need TikZmark: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark?lang=en I have not used it myself, so I can not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite easy to do with `pstricks`, and more specifically  with `pst-node`:

```
\documentclass[x11names]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}


\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
  \begin{align*}
    D(\lambda,x) & = f(x) + \lambda'g(x) \quad \lambda\geqslant 0 \\
    \intertext{the dual is given as:}
    \lambda^{*} & = \arg\{ \max_{\lambda}D(\lambda,\Rnode{X}{x^{*}}) \} \\
                 & = \arg\{ \max_{\lambda}D(\lambda) \}
  \end{align*}
  \nput[labelsep =1cm]{-30}{X}{\Rnode[vref=1.5pt]{C}{\color{red}const}}
  \ncdiagg[arrows=->, arrowinset =0.15, linewidth=1.5pt, linecolor=SteelBlue3, angleA=180, nodesepA=3pt, nodesepB=1pt, armA=6mm]{C}{X}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  Is it possible to have this also done with `tikz`?  Thanks?

Comment: I guess so, but I don't know TikZ very well. I proposed this solution in `pstricks` because the code is short and very clear.