# Arrow to constant in align environment using tikz

Tags: align, tikz-arrows

this question is building of the elegant solution posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297698/arrow-to-constant-in-align-environment), offered by [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard).

I wanted to get an alternate solution using `tikz`.

Here is the code with my failed attempt (commented out) trying to implement `tikz`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,,arrows,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  D(\lambda,x) = & ~ f(x) + \lambda'g(x) \quad \lambda\geqslant 0\\
\intertext{the dual is given as:}
\lambda^{*} = & ~ \arg\{ \max_{\lambda}D(\lambda,x^{*}) \}\\
            = & ~ \arg\{ \max_{\lambda}D(\lambda) \}
\end{align*}

\vspace{2cm}

%Tikz attempt

%\begin{align*}
%\tikz{\node$\{D(\lambda,x) = & ~ f(x) + \lambda'g(x) \quad \lambda\geqslant 0\\
%\intertext{the dual is given as:}
%\lambda^{*} = & ~ \arg\{ \max_{\lambda}D(\lambda,\subnode{d1}{$x^{*}$}) \}$};}\\
%                = & ~ \arg\{ \max_{\lambda}D(\lambda) \}
%\end{align*}

%\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
%\draw[blue,thick,->] (d1) to [in=90,out=245] + (198:2.5cm) node[anchor=north,text = black] {const.};
%\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I added the output of your code since is it not clear what you want without looking at the link you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only `tikz` the bits that really need `tikz`ing.  Leave the equation alone and just stick a judicious `tikzmark` where you want to point to, then put the arrow and text in a separate picture (as you have it).

```
\documentclass{book}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297831/86}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,,arrows,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  D(\lambda,x) = & ~ f(x) + \lambda'g(x) \quad \lambda\geqslant 0\\
\intertext{the dual is given as:}
\lambda^{*} = & ~ \arg\{ \max_{\lambda}D(\lambda,x^{*}\tikzmark{a}) \}\\
            = & ~ \arg\{ \max_{\lambda}D(\lambda) \}
\end{align*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[blue,thick,<-] (pic cs:a) to [in=90,out=-45] + (-18:2.5cm) node[anchor=north,text = black] {const.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I put the `\tikzmark` *after* the `x^{*}` because it seemed better to have the label on the right of the equation.

[image: pointing to a term in an equation]