# Put arrow on elements of a set with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, labels, tikz-arrows

I need to mark some elements of a set with arrow in latex using tikz.
I tried tikz-cd but it doesn't seem the right choice.

[image: mark elements of a set with tikz]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this recent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297844/99343):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,,arrows,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}

\begin{document}

This is just some filler text to get a longer line so we can show off that the vertical spacing is about right. The set
%
\vspace{2em}% add some vertical space so the arrows don't run into the text
\begin{equation}
    \{(\overset{\mathstrut\tikzmark{f1}}{\textcolor{green!50!black}{1}}, 2), (\textcolor{green!50!black}{3}, 4), \dots, (\overset{\mathstrut\tikzmark{fx}}{\textcolor{green!50!black}{x}},y)\}
\end{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \coordinate (f1) at (pic cs:f1);
    \coordinate (fx) at (pic cs:fx);

    \path (f1) ++(.1em, 2em) node (f1text) {$F(1)$};
    \draw[->] (f1text) -> (f1);

    \path (f1text -| fx) ++(.1em, 0) node (fxtext) {$F(x)$};
    \draw[->] (fxtext) -> (fx);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
has arrows pointing to it.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I'm using `\overset` to put the `\tikzmark` above the element it's supposed to refer to. The positions of these marks are then available in the `tikzpicture`. I'm then calculating relative coordinates using these nodes to place the texts, making sure that they're vertically aligned.

Because the picture is an overlay, we need to manually add some space to ensure that the labels don't overlap the preceding text.

You need to compile the document twice to get the arrows to point to the right location.

Comment: what is the counterpart for `\overset`, i.e. to point the arrow _underneath_ some thing and completely at center?

Comment: I found it:

I just put `[xshift=5pt]` before the desired point, e.g. `([xshift=5pt]f1text)->`